# How to register COM dll in VS2008

Tags: asp.net

hi i have crated dll of my c# application and Have signed it but m not getting how to register it as i want to access it in my asp application so plz can u provide the steps required for registration

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [regasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(VS.71).aspx) in order to expose the managed assembly as COM component:

```
regasm.exe /codebase YourAssembly.dll
```

Once registered you could use it as you would any COM object.

Comment: yes i tried but giving error like make sure you typed name correctly
In my BIN folder there is dll m not getting what missing